# Converting JSON to XML in Java; Trouble with root

Tags: java, json, xml

I am trying to convert a JSON payload to XML in order to then send it to a cosmos database. I keep encountering the following error:

```
[2023-03-14T15:03:25.573Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpHandler' (Failed, Id=afd4b437-4ea6-4d0d-a406-357c263563b5, Duration=2377ms)
[2023-03-14T15:03:25.575Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpHandler. Newtonsoft.Json: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: #. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

I believe that this is occurring because I am trying to append a root payload path to make it a valid XML payload. This is the function that I use to convert to an XML string:

```
public String JsonToXml(String payload) {
    JSONObject myPayload = new JSONObject(payload);
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
    root.put("payload", myPayload);
    return XML.toString(root);
}
```

And here is my handler:

```
public class Handler {
    @FunctionName("HttpHandler")
    public HttpResponseMessage runHttp(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> req, 
            @CosmosDBOutput(name = "database",
            databaseName = "hyperscalerapi-cosmos-dev",
            collectionName = "Items",
            connectionStringSetting = "cosmosDBConnectionString")
          OutputBinding<String> outputItem,final ExecutionContext context) {
        try {
            // request to String (payload)
            String payload = req.getBody().get();

            Transform p = new Transform();

            // JSON to XML
            payload = p.JsonToXml(payload);

            // Create in Cosmos (XML) NOTE: YOU MUST COMMENT OUT import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Document
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(payload)));
            document.setNodeValue(context.getInvocationId().toString());
            document.normalize();
            outputItem.setValue(document.toString());
            
            return req.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Data logged").build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log the exception
            context.getLogger().severe(e.toString());
            return req.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An error occurred").build();
        }
    }
```

Why am I getting this error? Any help would be appreciated! If I try to complete this without appending the payload root, I also get an error saying the XML is invalid so I am pretty sure that I need the root. Finally, this is the JSON payload that I am passing in:

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "sku": "20223",
    "price": 23.95,
    "shipTo": {
        "name": "Jane Smith",
        "address": "123 Maple Street",
        "city": "Pretendville",
        "state": "NY",
        "zip": "12345"
    },
    "billTo": {
        "name": "Me",
        "address": "123 Maple Street",
        "city": "Pretendville",
        "state": "NY",
        "zip": "12345"
    }
}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library has static method U.jsonToXml(json)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

    String json = "{\n" +
        "    \"name\": \"John Smith\",\n" +
        "    \"sku\": \"20223\",\n" +
        "    \"price\": 23.95,\n" +
        "    \"shipTo\": {\n" +
        "        \"name\": \"Jane Smith\",\n" +
        "        \"address\": \"123 Maple Street\",\n" +
        "        \"city\": \"Pretendville\",\n" +
        "        \"state\": \"NY\",\n" +
        "        \"zip\": \"12345\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    \"billTo\": {\n" +
        "        \"name\": \"Me\",\n" +
        "        \"address\": \"123 Maple Street\",\n" +
        "        \"city\": \"Pretendville\",\n" +
        "        \"state\": \"NY\",\n" +
        "        \"zip\": \"12345\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}";
    String xml = U.jsonToXml(json);
    System.out.println(xml);
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <name>John Smith</name>
  <sku>20223</sku>
  <price number="true">23.95</price>
  <shipTo>
    <name>Jane Smith</name>
    <address>123 Maple Street</address>
    <city>Pretendville</city>
    <state>NY</state>
    <zip>12345</zip>
  </shipTo>
  <billTo>
    <name>Me</name>
    <address>123 Maple Street</address>
    <city>Pretendville</city>
    <state>NY</state>
    <zip>12345</zip>
  </billTo>
</root>
```